# How to embed interactive bokeh plots in a HTML/php site

Tags: python, python-2.7, lamp, digital-ocean, bokeh

I have a container website into which I'd like to embed an interactive bokeh plot. To start a bokeh server I ran `bokeh serve scripts/test.py --port 5010 --host ip-address-of-my-server:5010` in the server shell.

I now have two questions:

- If I navigate to ip-address-of-my-server:5010/test, the connection times out and I don't see anything. I assume there's something wrong with the py-file. Locally, I run

  ```
  p = make_figure()
  show(p)
  ```

  On the server I tried

  ```
  p = make_figure()
  curdoc().add_root(p)
  ```

  Is that the correct way to get the graph to display?
- If I do have a graph, how do I integrate it into a site? I have a site that is called "Visualizations". I now want visitors to go to that site, see the embedded bokeh plot and be able to press some buttons and have their personal graph change a little. 
  Literally, what code (php? js?) do I have to write to see the graph? Or should it be an iframe?

I'm running a digital ocean droplet with LAMP preinstalled on Ubuntu 16.04, Bokeh 0.12.4, Python 2.7.